Запятые в начале предложений после "или" и после "ведь" нужны ли в этих предложениях?
1. Или (?) быть может, знаешь на собственном опыте?
2. Ведь (?) если мы оставим их, они не поймут.

Мой вариант:

Или, быть может, знаешь на собственном опыте?

Ведь если мы оставим их, они не поймут.


Пояснение

Разделительный союз ИЛИ в начале предложения на практике обычно отделяется от вводного слова, см. тему.

Виктор Пелевин. Бэтман Аполло (2013). Или, быть может, мы от такого сна просыпаемся?

Ведь — частица в роли присоединительного союза
ВЕДЬ. I. частица. Употр. для усиления основного 
содержания всего высказывания (предположения, 
утверждения, вопроса и т.п.) или выделения, подчёркивания 
отдельного слова. В. приди я вовремя, этого бы не 
случилось. В. поступи я иначе, всё обошлось бы. 
II. союз. 1. Присоединяет предложения, содержащие 
указание на причину, обоснование предыдущего 
высказывания. Полагаемся на тебя, ты в. один знаешь 
дорогу. Пора домой, в. уже поздно. 2. Несмотря на то, 
что; хотя. В. и сил нет, а работаешь. В. говорил вам, да 
не послушались.




§ 95. Вводные слова не отделяются запятой от союзов, стоящих в начале предложения.

Или быть может, знаешь на собственном опыте?

Ведь если мы оставим их, они не поймут.


